# Offloading comments/login to thirdparty from Expressionengine to speed up website

Tags: login, comments

Developing for potential high traffic website (Startup) which will be kind of like a news website ( Heavy on reading).
One of the ways user will interact will be through comments. Thus a social login comment, and threaded comment is in consideration.

Question

Will offloading the login/comment/analytics to third party like disqus/livefyre/ intense debate etc will have any positive impact in sense that more concurrent users can be handled by the server.
i.e. will having logged in users vs having NO logged in users will have better performance.
e.g. Full page Static caching can be potentially used if you have no comments/login as Javascript will will be used for both login/comment and analytics

Note: This maybe not expression engine specific, even then what is opinion for handling high traffic with good efficiency for read heavy site.

Edited for simplicity.

Comment: Please break your question up here, you're actually asking many different questions, making it very difficult for there to be a single accepted answer. Plus, much of this is unrelated to ExpressionEngine.

Comment: I agree with you, Let me modify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you only need login to post said comments?

Perhaps all you need is [Disqus](https://disqus.com/)? Modules already available : [CX Disqus Comments](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/cx-disqus-comments), [Alternatives](https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=disqus&addon_version_support=ee2)

Of course, by outsourcing your comments and social login to Discus (or another) you will lose the overhead of managing and developing an EE userbase, however if you wanted to sync your users so they can also log into your site that will work.

You'll benifit from having your comments/discussions/arguements off site, likewise unless you want to sync your users you'll do away with the EE member stuff completely. YOu could use a social login plugin to extend this to cover native polls ect, continuing the "No need for my own members" philosophy.

As for loading and traffic, EE can handle large user bases (I have a couple of sites with numbers in the hundreds of thousands) however by using social login you're avoiding session handling in EE, posibly gaining a bit from the asyncronous nature. Of course this does add a JS dependancy to your site...

Comment: Comments/Polling .

Comment: Ok well disqus supports 'non-anonymous' commentin, threaded comments, social login so could easily cover your commenting needs. For polling I'm not sure if Discus can cover it however there are modules (CX can do this) that will sync your disqus commenters to your EE user base, potentually allowing EE native poll's. I've added some load info in an edit above for you.

Comment: Wish there was a better commenting system which we could host which could be real-time or with more functionality.  http://tildehash.com/?page=hashover seems promising but is it production ready. Thank you Blatant for you valuable insight.

Comment: I'm sure there are options, however the need for an EE plugin kind of says you need a common, well supported one. You could just bite the bullet and impliment a different one yourelf (they usually have integration guides), get on Google and shop for one you like, I in no way encourage Disqus over any other,its just most common!